# Magento2 - How to change Product Images?

Tags: magento2.3

I would like to change the images of the `Products` in `Magento2` but since I am new to magento I don't know in which file I should put my images.

Is there a php file to edit or directory where I can put my photos.

Thank you for your answers

Comment: You can change images from admin catalog > Product edit any product and you can change/upload image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read more about the view.xml file. Where you can resize the image. [Example](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-images.html)

Comment: Thank you, I will read it and I will come back to you

Comment: I read view.xml but I need to know how to change them directly in the server to which folder I need to go?